# What model/make are this Freewheel and Freehub?

Tags: repair, identify-this-bike, freewheel, freehub

I am in the process of overhauling my old Motobécane racing bike and I'd like to replace the freewheel, if reasonable. However, there is no indication of who made it (the bike shop couldn't help) and I've never seen a hub like this online.

The Freewheel has a lock ring with splines on the outside and I'm wondering which tool to use to screw it tight on the hub.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a Helicomatic. Once you know the name, there is plenty of information on the Internet.

Comment: I assume if I wanted to get something newer I'm looking at replacing the entire wheel for replacing the hub, yes?

Comment: Technically you could reuse the rim with new hub and spokes but that's a lot of work for a small saving. Old hubs like this are narrower than anything made since 1990s, so if you upgrade to a modern hub you will have to bend the frame to fit it.

Comment: @ojs: Unless you want to rebuild the bike as a vintage machine and the braking surfaces of the rim are too worn to be safely re-used.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to replace that freewheel with anything new you can buy on the market; your only options will be old stock or take-offs that you can find on eBay, etc.